# Are keys unique in resource bundles?

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

What is the use of `public final String[] getStringArray(String key)` in [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)?
Aren't `keys` in properties files unique? Would this ever return more than one value? If not why does it return an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully the documentation of `ResourceBundle`, its says that: -

> Resource bundles belong to families whose members share a common base
>   name, but whose names also have additional components that identify
>   their locales.

**Also: -**

> Resource bundles contain key/value pairs. The keys uniquely identify a
>   locale-specific object in the bundle.

So, keys are only unique for a particular locale. In two different locale, you can have keys that are same. That is why the return type is `String[]`.

And for the method - [`getStringArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getStringArray%28java.lang.String%29): -

> Gets a string array for the given key from this resource bundle or one
>   of its parents.

Answer (score 0):

The value in a `ResourceBundle` does not have to be a `String`, the value can be any Object. In this case you expect it to be a `String[]`.

From the javadoc you linked:

Keys:

> Resource bundles contain key/value pairs. The keys uniquely identify a
>   locale-specific object in the bundle.

Values:

> Keys are always Strings. In this example, the keys are "OkKey" and
>   "CancelKey". In the above example, the values are also Strings--"OK"
>   and "Cancel"--but they don't have to be. The values can be any type of
>   object.